# How do I implement a saving system into my Tkinter game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I need to write something so it saves the variables and game state so that when you save and then press load you return to where you left off. It all needs to be saved into a file I tried using the pickle system but I got confused 
So I need to save the page current function and then save the current stat variables and when load is pressed the stats replace the old ones in the variable and it moves straight the page function

```
class Charater(object):
def __init__(self, Name, Allias, Pounds, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3, Stat4, Stat5, Stat6, Stat7, Stat8, Stat9):
    self.Name = Name
    self.Allias = Allias
    self.Pounds = Pounds
    self.Stat1= Stat1
    self.Stat2= Stat2
    self.Stat3 = Stat3
    self.Stat4 = Stat4
    self.Stat5= Stat5
    self.Stat6= Stat6
    self.Stat7= Stat7
    self.Stat8= Stat8
    self.Stat9= Stat9
```

This is my charater class

on start `Player = Charater("Tim", "Fighter", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Then when I save

```
def Save_Game():
global Player
pickle_out = open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME , "wb")
pickle.dump(Player, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

When I load 
`def Load_Game():
    global Player
    pickle_in = open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, "rb")
    Player = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    print(Player)`

I'm not sure on how to save and load the current function yet

I'm currently learning python and I just started so my apologise for any bad programming practises etc

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you choose to make a game in Tkinter rather than Pygame?

Comment: I didn't know pygame existed and also pygame is a bit overkill

Comment: Could you assign an integer to each point of progression so when a particular integer is loaded from the pickle, you take the user straight to the corresponding screen?

Comment: That's a great idea which I'll try but the pickle file isn't loading correctly thanks